# Android AlarmManager (sometimes) provides extra notification

Tags: c#, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am working on an application that uses the AlarmManager to generate a notification for the user at a later date.  The Alarm always arrives (on the devices tested) but one device (Samsung Galaxy Tab3, Android 4.4.2) receives 2 notifications (presumably one from the alarmManager, and one from the broadcast receiver of the app).  The code for both is of course the same, and I haven't seen this issue before.[image: Nexus 5] [image: Galaxy Tab]

The code is written in C# for Xamarin, but it is pretty vanilla.  The AlarmManager creates a broadcast with a broadcast filter that will be picked up elsewhere in the app (and that works fine):

private PendingIntent CreateIntent (Models.Notifications.LocalNotificationModel notification, PendingIntentFlags flag)
        {
            if (notification.IsActive) {
                //Create the broadcast intent
                var broadcastIntent = new Intent (BROADCASTFILTER);

```
            //Add information to the receiver of what should be done about the notification
            var id = notification.Id;
            var message = notification.Message;
            var badgeNumber = notification.BadgeNumber;
            var dateOfEvent = notification.EventDateTime;
            var iconPath = notification.IconPath;
            var isActive = notification.IsActive;
            var isOverride = notification.IsOverride;

            //Needs extra information to create the notification
            broadcastIntent.PutExtra (ID, id);
            broadcastIntent.PutExtra (MESSAGE, message);
            broadcastIntent.PutExtra (DATEOFEVENT, dateOfEvent.ToShortDateString () + " " + dateOfEvent.ToShortTimeString ());

            //Get the broadcast as pending intent
            var source = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast (_context, (int)id, broadcastIntent, flag);

            return source;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void Add(Models.Notifications.LocalNotificationModel notification)
    {
        if (!_isInitialized)
            throw new ApplicationException("LocalNotificationService is not initialized");

        var source = CreateIntent (notification,PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        //Convert the notification to milliseconds since epoch
        var sinceEpoch = notification.EventDateTime.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var msSinceEpoch = (long)sinceEpoch.TotalMilliseconds;

        //Assign the pending intent to the alarmmanager
        _alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, msSinceEpoch, source);
    }
```

Comment: You can notice that two same notification is there but it view is different, i.e 1. blue orange icon notification : Title : Garlie 2) another notification : Title : Garlie and descriptoin is TIME. Please check the code. May be you put two notification

Comment: You are correct that the 2 notifications are not the same.  Is there any way that I could be signaling the AlarmManager to generate a notification automatically?  

The problem that I am experiencing is that is that I have no idea where the second notification is coming from.  I have placed breakpoints at all instances of .Notify() and only one is hit, exactly one time (and the second notification is generated before that breakpoint is hit).

Comment: Search in your project : alarmManager.set

Comment: There are only 2 places, 1 as in the post above, and the other as part of the push notification registration.  I have verified that the second version is not called though.  Additionally my broadcastReceiver is called only once.

Back on topic: I'm fairly certain that the other notification is NOT coming from my project (or at least not directly).  Is there any way that the AlarmManager could be generating this notification?  And is there a way to disable it?

Comment: That not possible that OS generate notification.

Comment: That was my understanding as well but this only appears on the galaxy tab 3, and with the debugger I can't find any other place that it could be generated from my code.  Thanks for looking with me.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on my part, there was a proof of concept version of the application on the tablet, it was a different app but used the same bundle ID, and as a result received the same broadcast.